# Google App Engine: Can't create second app on same developer machine ("The project already contains an App Engine application")

Tags: google-app-engine

Somewhere on my SSD is an ongoing, actively managed Google App Engine project. I develop it on this machine and I am always able to deploy it successfully with `gcloud app deploy`.

Now i wanted to create another Google App Engine project.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. I created the directory on my developer machine (Mac)

`cd mynewproject`

2. I created the project in google app engine console

`mynewproject`

3. Then i wanted to create the new app as follows:

`gcloud app create`

### Result:

But this gives the following error:

> $ gcloud app create ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) The project
>   [oldproject] already contains an App Engine application in region
>   [europe-west].  You can deploy your application using `gcloud app
>   deploy`.

I am pretty sure that i moved to another directory far outside of the directory for "oldproject".

Also the new project is listed in the Google App Engine console with all other projects.

How can i work on this project on the same machine without to need removing my other GAE-project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create only one App Engine app per Google Cloud project.

If your new project is related to the old one, You can create a new App Engine service in the same Google Cloud project: In your `app.yaml`, you can specify a service name: `service: [SERVICE_NAME]`. Now when you run `gcloud app deploy`, it will deploy a new service to the same project.

If your new project is not related to the old one, you should just create a new Cloud Console project and then create an App Engine app for this one.
To do so, either use the command line: `gcloud projects create [PROJECT_ID]` or simply browse to https://console.cloud.google.com to create it. 
Then, you can either:

- use `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project [PROJECT_ID]` to deploy to this project.
- tell `gcloud` that you are now working within that project: `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`

Answer (score 0):

The `gcloud` command has configuration options and one of those options is to set the default project.  At some point, you set the default project to `oldproject` and that is why the command is trying to recreate `oldproject`.

One solution is to unset the default project in your configuration.  There are probably other solutions.  I think you can create multiple configurations, but the interface for this is klunky so I've never delved into it.

It is probable easier to just create a new project at console.google.com.  Though to deploy and do other things, you'll still need to unset the default project or create another configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I think the GCP project was just too old (at least a few years old), and I had to delete it and create new project in order to make it work... I did use command "gcloud app describe" and tried to create a new project in the GCP web console as well, both did not work...

Comment: Hmm, do you consider this to be a solution to the described problem? Or is this more of a "Me too." ?

Comment: Mainly add my 2 cents, hopefully it can help others too

Comment: Please rephrase your 2 cents so that the part which is on-topic, i.e. an answer to the question, is more obvious. Move the non-answering part into a comment if you like.